# Sqlite get max id not working (?)

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

Im using this:

```
SELECT * 
WHERE id=MAX(id) 
FROM history;
```

But my query is empty. I have also tried this (This one works):

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id 
FROM history;
```

But obviusly my query only contains the max_id key. What am I doing wrong with the first one?

Comment: select * from history where id=(select max(id) from history);

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to add another level of `select` for the `MAX`, like this:

```
SELECT * 
WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) from history)
FROM history;
```

A better approach would be to order by `id` in descending order, and limit the output to a single row:

```
SELECT *
FROM history
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually most simple query to get the max value of a column in sqlite is:

```
select MAX(id) from table;
```

Comment: This works, I have tried it just now and it appears to be robust. I also used the `MIN` to get the minimum value as well `SELECT MIN(ROWID) FROM TABLE_NAME`

Answer (score 0):

SELECT top 1
FROM history
ORDER BY id DESC

Comment: I just wonder, do you think that your answer is necessary and adds some new information to this post in addition to the accepted answer? It's just that we don't want StackOverflow to get unnecessary overcrowded. :)