# How to query last inserted row in database sqflite

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I wanted to get last row from database. I have come to realize there is only rawQuery on the documentation.

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE id=?', []");
```

So how do i manipulate the above query to fetch last row by id?

Comment: For future reference, I got it working from this sqlite answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29086747/7351826). Use the second solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this, assuming you have self-incrementing field:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE id=(SELECT max(id) FROM $tableName, []" );
```

Comment: Sorry for the late replay i was busy on something else. I just tried your code. But it doesn't work. Gives me the below error.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 1025 pos 12: '_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.created': is not true.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
_db.rawQuery("SELECT max(id) FROM $tableName");
```